# Can I return Laravel config data conditionally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a **payment.php** config file. The values it holds are used in my app:

```
<?php    

    return [

        'perUser' => 0.25,
        'perPost' => 0.10

    ];
```

Now, let's say the payment values are going to change starting from a specific date:

```
<?php

if (date('d-m-Y', strtotime(time()) === '01.12.2017') {

        // New values
        return [
            'perUser' => 0.55,
            'perPost' => 0.25
        ];
    } else {

        // Default values up to the new date
        return [
            'perUser' => 0.25,
            'perPost' => 0.10
        ];
    }
```

Is it OK to do the check directly in the config file or is it not safe to do it, as the config is cached by Laravel?

Comment: The configs are only cached if you call the config:cache artisan command, if you are caching your configs you could run a task to periodically clear and re cache these configs if you need  artisan cache:clear.

Comment: Makes sense - [caching config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching). We don't do it on production, but it doesn't mean we won't in the future. I will come up with something else.

Answer (score 1):

no but you can use another way:

`payment.php`  file :

```
return [
  'up' => [
        'perUser' => 0.55,
        'perPost' => 0.25
  ],
  'down' => [
        'perUser' => 0.25,
        'perPost' => 0.10
  ]
];
```

in your controller:

```
$r=date('d-m-Y', strtotime(time()) === '01.12.2017'?'up':'down';
echo config($r.'perUser');
```